# Solve system of non-linear equations $\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{1}{(y-x)^2}-\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}= \frac{1}{y^2}+\frac{1}{(y-x)^2}-\frac{1}{(1-y)^2}=0$

Tags: systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

Whilst solving a problem, the following system of non-linear equations arose:

$$0= \frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{1}{(y-x)^2}-\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$$

$$0= \frac{1}{y^2}+\frac{1}{(y-x)^2}-\frac{1}{(1-y)^2}$$

I have tried to solve it via brute force and by trying to add them both in a way that could give me the answer, but I still haven't got it.

I can't manage to find the intersection of the two parametric equations that these equations give. I know that I can find approximate solutions with the Wolfram Alpha tool, but I would like to know, if any, an analytical or strong numerical way to proceed.

**Note:** Out of all the solutions ($8$ it seems, $4$ real and $4$ complex), I only need the one that takes real values for $x$ and $y$, with $0<x<y<1$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take the cue of $0<x<y<1$ and observe that $x+y=1$ satisfies both equations
$$\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{1}{(y-x)^2}-\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}=
\frac{1}{y^2}+\frac{1}{(y-x)^2}-\frac{1}{(1-y)^2}=0$$
which leads to $\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{1}{(1-2x)^2}-\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}=0$, or
$$x^4+6x^3-11x^2+6x -1=0$$
Factorize
$$[x^2+3(1+\sqrt2)x-(1+\sqrt2)][x^2+3(1-\sqrt2)x-(1-\sqrt2)]=0$$
to obtain the solution in the domain $(0,1)$

$$x= \frac12\left( \sqrt{31+22\sqrt2}-3\sqrt2-3\right)
$$
$$ y= \frac12\left(- \sqrt{31+22\sqrt2}+3\sqrt2+5\right)$$

Comment: It seems that this is the method to obtain the exact answers I'm looking for. Would there be a way to arrive to this answer without assuming $x+y=1$? Or demonstrating that $x+y=1$ is the only solution that adjusts to the condition $0<x<y<1$? To arrive to the generalized solution for my problem I think I must not assume that $x+y=1$ holds. Nevertheless, this is the answer and method I was looking for, Will accept it tomorrow when I have though on the other answers and these two new questions. Thanks Quanto!

Comment: @Quanto : I agree. Smart . Up-vote !

Comment: @Curveatour - Often, systems of equations such as yours stem from practical fields, e.g. engineering, physical, etc., where the solutions have their practical contents. So, the method employed here, though not complete, is practically desirable. On the other hand, you could just treat it as a pure math problem, and eliminate $y$ to get a high-order polynomial equation in $x$ to cover all roots, real and imaginary.

Answer (score 4):

Provided that $x\ne0;\;x\ne 1;\;y\ne0;\;y\ne 1;\;x\ne y$ we simplify the denominators and get
$$
\begin{cases}
-x^4+4 x^2 y-2 x y^2-2 x y+y^2=0\\
-2 x^2 y+x^2+4 x y^2-2 x y+y^4-4 y^3+2 y^2=0\\
\end{cases}\tag{1}
$$

add the two equation in $(1)$
$$-x^4+4 x^2 y-2 x^2 y+x^2+4 x y^2-2 x y^2-2 x y-2 x y+y^4-4 y^3+2 y^2+y^2=0$$
which can be factored
$$(y-x) (x+y-1) \left(x^2+x+y^2-3 y\right)$$

First factor $y-x=0$ is discarded for the conditions above

$x+y-1=0\to y=1-x$ give
$$x^4+6 x^3-11 x^2+6 x-1=0$$
two real solutions
$$(x=-7.5619;\;y=8.5619);\;(x=0.31926;\;y=0.68074)$$

$x^2+y^2+x-3 y=0$

I can't see elementary methods to get the other solutions. A graph can help, though.

---

$$...$$
[image]

Comment: Seems like a method I will look into with more detail, but still doesn't find the solutions I reffered to: [here they are](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=systems+of+equations+calculator&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22SolveSystemOf2EquationsCalculator%22%2C+%22equation1%22%7D+-%3E%221%2Fx%5E2+-+1%2F%28y-x%29%5E2+-+1%2F%281-x%29%5E2%22&assumption=%22FSelect%22+-%3E+%7B%7B%22SolveSystemOf2EquationsCalculator%22%7D%7D&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22SolveSystemOf2EquationsCalculator%22%2C+%22equation2%22%7D+-%3E%221%2Fy%5E2+%2B+1%2F%28y-x%29%5E2+-+1%2F%281-y%29%5E2%22), click on more solutions.

Comment: @Curveatour $x\approx 0.31926;\;y\approx 0.68074$ is not a solution. Try and plug in the second equation $-\frac{1}{(y-x)^2}+\frac{1}{y^2}-\frac{1}{(1-y)^2}$. You get about $-15.3$ and not zero.

Comment: Hi, in this comment it seems you have misplaced a minus sign that wasn't there initially.

Answer (score 1):

Using Groebner basis,

Eliminating $x$ we get

$$
y^8-12 y^7+34 y^6-52 y^5+131 y^4-188 y^3+126 y^2-40 y=-5
$$

and simplifying

$$
\left(y \left((y-1)^2 y-10\right)+5\right) (y (y ((y-10) y+13)-6)+1)=0
$$

NOTE

The roots in the range $0<x<y<1$ are

$$
\cases{
x = 0.3192601457911361\\
y = 0.6807398542088641
}
$$